# Editar texto de Toasts

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Estou fazendo um component toast em angular, não poderei usar componentes terceiros, porém preciso fazer com que o toast aberto permita com que eu atualize o seu texto na exibição.
Obs. Não tenho o codigo ainda, mas gostária de uma ideia se isso e possivel e se alguem teria algum exemplo, apenas da edição do texto contido no toast.